# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot round NaN value

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing a Jetpack Compose application, and I think a Slider is causing an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot round NaN value` which causes my app to crash.

However, it doesn't give me any hints as to where or what is causing it to happen, beyond that it seems like it may be related to a Box composable. Furthermore, if I remove the `Slider` from my view, it looks like it isn't happening, so it seems like it is because of this Composable.

The slider is getting updated periodically and gets a value from an externally determined factor.

Is there something obviously wrong, or what can I do to debug or identify the problem?

My library versions are:

```
androidx-activity = "1.4.0"
androidx-appcompat="1.4.0"
androidxAnnotation="1.2.0"
androidx-core="1.7.0"
compose="1.1.1"
```

Here is my code

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: MyViewModel? = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.init()
    }
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Slider(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = viewModel.sliderPosition,
                    onValueChange = viewModel::onSliderValueChange
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel {
    var sliderPosition: Float by mutableStateOf(0f)
    fun onSliderValueChange(value: Float) { 
        sliderPosition = value
    }
    
    private fun tickerFlow(period: Duration, initialDelay: Duration = Duration.ZERO) = flow {
        delay(initialDelay)
        while (true) {
            emit(Unit)
            delay(period)
        }
    }
    
    fun init() {
        tickerFlow(period = .1.seconds, initialDelay = 0.seconds)
        .onEach { 
            sliderPosition = getExternallyDeterminedSliderPositionValue()
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.app.android, PID: 29210
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot round NaN value.
        at kotlin.math.MathKt__MathJVMKt.roundToInt(MathJVM.kt:1132)
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(Density.kt:73)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.IntrinsicMeasureScope$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(IntrinsicMeasureScope.kt:25)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(MeasureScope.kt:25)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$measureScope$1.roundToPx-0680j_4(LayoutNode.kt:493)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:361)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1317)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1313)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.forceMeasureTheSubtree(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:271)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.forceMeasureTheSubtree(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:670)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:115)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(BoxWithConstraints.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:64)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:355)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.606 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:781)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.material.MinimumTouchTargetModifier.measure-3p2s80s(TouchTarget.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:658)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1798)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1317)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1313)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:662)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner$DefaultImpls.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:182)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:846)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21884)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:725)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:731)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:840)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3944)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3026)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1885)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8508)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.606 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot round NaN value.
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at kotlin.math.MathKt__MathJVMKt.roundToInt(MathJVM.kt:1132)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(Density.kt:73)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.IntrinsicMeasureScope$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(IntrinsicMeasureScope.kt:25)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$DefaultImpls.roundToPx-0680j_4(MeasureScope.kt:25)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$measureScope$1.roundToPx-0680j_4(LayoutNode.kt:493)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:361)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.610 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1317)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1313)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.forceMeasureTheSubtree(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:271)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.forceMeasureTheSubtree(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:670)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:118)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:115)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(BoxWithConstraints.kt:67)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:64)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:355)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:781)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.material.MinimumTouchTargetModifier.measure-3p2s80s(TouchTarget.kt:74)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:658)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.611 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1798)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1317)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1313)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:170)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:662)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner$DefaultImpls.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:182)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:846)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21884)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20754)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4542)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4514)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20709)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:725)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:731)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:840)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3944)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3718)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3026)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1885)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8508)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.612 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
2022-03-31 10:27:00.613 29210-29210/com.mycompany.app.android E/UncaughtExceptionHandler:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Are you calculating the size or position of a composable? Might be that the result is NaN and once it tries to round it from float (or double) to int (for pixels), it crashes.

Comment: It's almost impossible to help you without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to localize the code that crashes by disabling parts of app one by one. I'd start with `BoxWithConstraints`, as it's contained in the logs, but it may be used internally by some other Compose elements.

Comment: What values do you get from `getExternallyDeterminedSliderPositionValue` before the crash? It's not defined, and without it your code works fine

Comment: @PylypDukhov I think it's a red herring and doesn't matter, because the data type of sliderPosition is of datatype Float (non nullable). I've updated my question to reflect this, my bad not including it, in my real code it's implied.

Comment: Well, looks like you're getting NaN from _somewhere_, and that method is currently the only suspect. Non-nullable Float can still be NaN (Float.NaN, literally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is that I didn't realize Floats can be NaN, and a NaN value was being returned from the `getExternallyDeterminedSliderPositionValue` function.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue by adding Composable view into Fragment. Problem was I haven't added Theme over Composable view. So make sure if your having theme in your app check whether you forget to add Theme block above composable view class.
It fixed my issue. Hope it will help you.